# User Access Authorization for Web Resources

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-8

Im refactoring a large internal legacy application and part of the stuff I want to get rid is the  widespread code repetition.

I'm starting with the way the website checks if a User can access a route e.g., '/admin` and which parts should be rendered or not.

I made this little function and works pretty well but wanted to see if you could take a look into it and suggest improvements or point out problems with the way I built it.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
export default async function isAdmin(alias, policyOverride = null) {
    try {
        var authResult = false;
        const url = 'https://xxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/local/xxxx/';

        var adminRolePolicy = ['Admin', 'Dev', 'BaseUser']; //Default Admin Policy.

        var rolesBoundToAlias = (await axios.get(url + alias)).data //Fetch roles that the alias holds.

        if(policyOverride){
            adminRolePolicy = policyOverride;
        } //If a new policy is, override the default adminRolePolicy.

        authResult = 
            rolesBoundToAlias.some(role => adminRolePolicy.includes(role)); //If alias has any of the roles in the policy grant access.

        return authResult;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error when attempting to authorize user " + alias 
            + ". Access for this user has been denied, please try again."
            + "\nError: " + error);
        return false;
    }  
}
```

I added the `policyOverride` as an optional param so the function can accept an array with different roles... allowing for more flexibility.

One of the most simple applications for this function would be as follows:

```
import isAdmin from '../utils/authorization.js';
//Other stuff happens here.
//...
isAdmin(alias)
.then((authResult) => {
    if(authResult) {
        //Authorized to view content render this.
    }
    else {
        //Else render a 403 or something...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 4 → 2 Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use `const` for some variables, then use that (or `let`) for all variables. Avoid `var` unless you have a good reason - e.g. you really need a global variable and/or hoisting.

The variable `authResult` can be eliminated from function `isAdmin` since it only gets a default value assigned, which then gets overwritten before it is returned. The function could merely return the value from the call to `rolesBoundToAlias.some()`. The arrow function passed to `.some()` could be declared on the previous line if you want, in an effort to decrease line length. Actually you might be able to just use `Array.includes()` bound to the array of roles instead of an extra arrow function.

The name `adminRolePolicy` might be better named as `DEFAULT_ROLES`. I use all caps since it is more like a real constant that wouldn't change much - and could be declared outside the function if deemed appropriate. And while there is likely some overlap, `Dev` and `BaseUser` seem separate from the concept of `admin`.

Instead of calling the second parameter `policyOverride`, you could call it `roles` with the default of `DEFAULT_ROLES` - then there would be no need to assign the parameter to a different variable.